# Problems changing the title of a Tab

Tags: local.xml, tabs

I am trying to change the title of a new tab depending on the category ID of the product and I am getting this error message and i cant figure out why

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in
>   /home/senorehe/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Data.php

I know it is telling me what the problem is but i dont know why it is occurring as it works on my test server. This is my code which i have in Mage/Catalog/Helper/Data.php

```
 public function getTabName(){
    $currentCategoryId = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId(); 

    if ($currentCategoryId == '1168' || $currentCategoryId == '1169' || $currentCategoryId == '1174' || $currentCategoryId == '1175' || $currentCategoryId == '1177') 
    {
        return 'Size Guide'; 
    }
    return $this->__('Data Sheets');
}
```

and this is the local.xml code

```
<action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" >    
    <alias>pdf_tabbed</alias>
    <title helper="Catalog/getTabName" />
    <block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block>
    <template>catalog/product/view/pdf.phtml</template>
</action>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
$currentCategoryId = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();
```

use this

```
$currentCategoryId = null;
if (Mage::registry('current_category')) {
     $currentCategoryId = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i will accept when it lets me. So what was the reason for the error and why did your fix work, just so i know for the future

Comment: sometimes, depending on the url `Mage::registry('current_category')` returns null.